# Resolver problema de cor no richtextbox no C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Como faço para que eu clicar em `button1` o texto da `richTextBox2` torne-se uma determinada cor, e eu clicar em `button2` o texto a partir da barra de digitaçao vertical | torne-se da cor do `button2`, o meu código abaixo efetua a mudança de cor de todo o texto. Eu gostaria da ajuda de vocês, desde já obrigado!

Código:

```
   {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Green;

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }


        private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for algo simples como apenas procurar por um caractere e modificar a cor a partir dele, da para você fazer algo como:

```
int inicio = richTextBox2.Text.IndexOf('|');
if(inicio >= 0)
{
    richTextBox2.SelectionStart = inicio;
    richTextBox2.SelectionLength = richTextBox2.Text.Length - inicio;
    richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: o que acontece @Christian Beregula , no codigo que uso, nao consigo deixar duas cores ao mesmo tempo, ou o texto é vermelho inteiro, ou verde interio, acredito que o que vc demonstrou acima seria um tipo de `replace `

Comment: @Petrukio não entendi bem o que te impede de deixar o texto com duas cores ao mesmo tempo. No exemplo acima ele vai pegar da `|` até o final do texto da cor vermelha, mas nada impede de você controlar até onde você precisa que vá essa cor vermelha alterando o `SelectionLenght`.

Comment: fiz errado? eu coloquei assim o codigo do @Christian veja a imagem (http://i.imgur.com/5QzBTKA.png)

Comment: Seu objetivo é apenas dividir o texto em duas cores? Qual o texto que você esta usando que não esta funcionando o código? Imprimi o valor de `inicio`, que valor retorna?

Comment: Essa resposta solucionou seu problema @Petrukio? Caso não, eu tenho um método de extensão que pode te ajudar.

Comment: @jbueno funciono apos alterar umas partes, mas todo o conhecimento é valido, se puder contribuir, desde ja agradecido. meu esta assim agora (http://i.imgur.com/55igCtP.png)